Validate if CSV exists in cloud storage bucket
I have a .sqlx file of type “operations”, where I'm loading data from a CSV file into a table named “incidents”. However, this CSV file may or may not be present in the designated bucket. Since incidents don’t occur every day, the CSV file typically contains data from the previous date (e.g., a file named “test30042024”).
The issue arises when attempting to execute the process. If the CSV file is missing from the bucket, the execution fails. I wonder if there is a way to validate if it exists before trying to load it, so it does not break the script.
Here is what the sqlx script currently looks like:
config {
    type: "operations",
    hasOutput: true
}

js {

    function getYesterday() {
        const today = new Date();
        const localOffset = -(today.getTimezoneOffset() / 60);
        const peruOffset = -5; // Peru timezone offset (GMT-5)
        const offset = peruOffset - localOffset;

        const yesterday = new Date(today.getTime() - 24 * 3600 * 1000 + offset * 3600 * 1000);

        const dd = String(yesterday.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        const mm = String(yesterday.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
        const yyyy = yesterday.getFullYear();

        return dd + mm + yyyy;
    }

}


  LOAD DATA INTO
    project.dataset.incidents (incidentId Integer,
      name String,
      timestamp Integer)
  FROM FILES (skip_leading_rows=1, format = 'CSV',
      uris = ['gs://bucket/test${getYesterday()}.csv']);

and here is an example of how the CSV can look like:
incidentId,name,timestamp
1,SOMENAME,1714482000000
2,ANOTHERNAME,1714482000000
3,ANYNAME,1714485600000

I see some documentation about the LOAD DATA function but could not find anything that allows to do this kind of validation

Hi @david7596, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

Not possible through native SQL/Dataform. One way to achieve this though would be to create an external table that points at the bucket and uses these csv files as a source. Then a query against the table won't fail, it'd just return 0 rows if there's no file underneath.

one way you can do this is by not deleting the old gcs file, this way you will always have the reference for the load data, or if you want to take another approach, use the external table functions with the reference for gcs being the folder uris = ['gs://bucket/*.csv']) this way it will read all files inserted in csv, after that, use a hidden field called ,_file_name it will bring the name of the source in reference to the line, this way it is possible to filter by the file you need.
